# AngularJs inject google analytics script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to inject my google analytics script into my app. I have hard code this in the head of my index.html file

```
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    </script>
```

Here my the directive:

```
app.directive('googleAnalytics', function(configFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '../views/gaScript.html',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      configFactory.getconfigs().then(function(configs) {
          scope.gid = configs[0].ga_id;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

The directive uses this template in gaScript.html to inject the proper ga ID

```
<script>ga('create', '{{gid}}', 'auto');</script>
```

This is the html tag inside the body that gets replaced by the directive

```
<google-analytics></google-analytics>
```

The problem is I think the page is reading this `<script>ga('create', '{{gid}}', 'auto');</script>` as a string and not interpreting the script tag

Comment: What's in `'../views/gaScript.html'`?

Comment: @mparnisari this is what is inside gaScript.html `<script>ga('create', '{{gid}}', 'auto');</script>`

Comment: what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular version 1.4.7

Comment: @Jason if the template is a one liner why not just write it in the directive? Aside from that. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `scope.gid = configs[0].ga_id;`?

Comment: @mparnisari I originally had the entire google script in the template but have pulled out the main function call for testing. the gid works fine. this is the not problem. the problem is I think the page is not reading the script tag as javascript but instead as a string?

Comment: The reason I think this is because when I inject the code and check in google analytics nothing happens but when I take the same code and hard code it in everything works

Comment: See this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/08/dynamically-injecting-script-tags-with-angularjs.aspx

Comment: I was looking at that page but got a little confused as how to implement for my needs

Comment: This is probably an issue of DOM parsing by the browser. Once it passes the DOM once (including all <script>), any script injections won't tell the browser to run those routines in a script tag. But I think a directive might be overkill. I have an idea you might try, but first do you have a controller defined at the application level?

Comment: @TSmith I am using a service configFactory that I think is at the application level

Comment: @TSmith I would love to simplify the code. Right now when the GA id changes in the db I have to refresh the screen to update the directive which I don't like. I would love for the GA id to update when ever the id changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of @mparnisari comments I was able to get it to work properly. Here is the final result in case this helps someone else.

This is hard coded in the head of the index.html page

```
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    </script>
```

This is the directive:

```
app.directive('googleAnalytics', function(configFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      configFactory.getconfigs().then(function(configs) {
          scope.gid = configs[0].ga_id;
          var scriptTag = angular.element(document.createElement("script"));
              scriptTag.text("ga('create', '"+scope.gid+"', 'auto');")
              element.append(scriptTag);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

This is the html tag inside the body of index.html the directive uses

```
<google-analytics></google-analytics>
```

My system has multiple users. this code allow each user to use their own GA id

Comment: I haven't used Google analytics, so I may be vastly mistaken, but why inject a script when you can call JS directly, i.e. change your link function to `link: function(scope) { ga('create', scope.gid, 'auto'); }`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I could not call js directly because the page does not read the script as a script tag but instead it interprets it as a string

Comment: No, I mean call Google's `ga()` function directly from the directive instead of generating a string that will become a script that will call `ga()`.

Comment: I was unaware that I could call the ga() directly. let me try that

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos not sure if I did it wrong but that did not work